# Is it possible to do conditional abbreviation in vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following abbreviation in my `.vimrc`:

```
:iab stdio #include <stdio.h>
```

Is it possible to make substitution only occur when `stdio` is not preceded by `<`, so that if I paste in code that has the line `#include <stdio.h>`, it does not expand into the following?

```
#include <#include <stdio.h>.h>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be an easier way than this but heres what I did.

```
function! InsertHeader(replacement, mapping)
    if getline('.')[col('.')-len(a:mapping)-2] != '<'
        return a: replacement
    endif
    return a:mapping
endfunction

iabbrev <expr> stdio InsertHeader('#include <stdio.h>', 'stdio')
```

I used a function that checks to see if the mapping is preceded with a `<` if it is return the mapping. If it isn't return what you return the replacement. The return value is what gets replaced.

---

Rereading the question it seems you are pasting the code in. Before pasting anything use

```
:set paste
```

This stops any of the abbreviations from activating. After pasting use

```
:set nopaste
```

(Or use `:set paste!` to toggle it)

Comment: If you use gvim instead of using vim inside a terminal, then vim handles communication with the clipboard, so it can usually distinguish between pasting and typing.  As a result, you do not have to worry about (re)setting the `'paste'` option if you use gvim.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather map it as following so that `stdio` will expand only if `<leader>` is pressed before it. So, if your `<leader>` is `,` then typing `,stdio` will expand it while typing only 
`stdio` will not expand it. You can try it out by adding the following line to `vimrc`(*but remember to disable your old abbreviation first).*

```
inoremap <leader>stdio #include <stdio.h>
```

However if you want as you asked in the question, you can take a cue from here on VimTips, which explains how to expand abbreviations only on shortcut

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip481

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use in [lh-brackets](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets) -> http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/map-tools/trunk/autoload/lh/cpp/brackets.vim#32  (Note: This is a callback function. Its result will get interpreted by lh-brackets framework)

`<` is expanded as `<`*cursor*`>` when preceded by `template`, `#include`, or the various casts.

Otherwise, In your case, you should have defined your abbreviation with `inoreab` (`:h inoreab`) (and `<buffer>` as well -> `:h :abbreviate-<buffer>`)